# Batch file : Renaming files based on parent subdir, accepting spaces and multiple iterations

Tags: windows, batch-file, recursion, rename

I've learnt a lot from this site and this is my first question ... hopefully I'll be able to give back to the community once I've honed my skills a bit further. I've researched it as best as I can, but I can't seem work out where I'm tripping up.

I have a number of files in a set of subdirectories like this;

```
Newspaper A
|-Monday
  |-Paper 1.pdf
  |-Paper 2.pdf
|-Tuesday
  |-Paper 1.pdf
  |-Paper 2.pdf
|-Wednesday
  |-Paper 1.pdf
  |-Paper 2.pdf
 ... etc
```

And I'm trying to make a batch file to rename the files to have a file-name that represents their folder name, i.e. the resultant files should be "Monday - Newspaper A - Paper 1.pdf". The batch file needs to be run each day even though only one set of papers is updated per day (due to the further processing that occurs each day), hence the need to check if the folder name already exists in the file-name and not rename the file (again) if it does. At the moment, each time I run the batch file it is prefixing the folder name again and again, so I suspect this is something to do with the findstr function perhaps not liking spaces in the names?

```
@echo off
for /d /r "C:\Test\Newspaper A\" %%D in (*.*) do (
   for /f "eol=: delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /a-d "%%D" ^| findstr /vbic:"%%~nD-"') do (
   ren "%%D\%%F" "%%~nD - Newspaper A - %%F"
   )
)
```

Any thoughts or solutions would be gratefully appreciated.

Regards.

Comment: In your `ren` command there are spaces aroud the dash that are not present in the `findstr` search string. Changing it makes any difference?

Comment: You're spot on there ... that was the cause of all of my issues with this script. I've now ammended it as such and it works fine;
    for /d /r "C:\Test\Newspaper A\" %%D in (*.*) do (
    for /f "eol=: delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /a-d "%%D" ^| findstr /vbic:"%%~nD-"') do (ren "%%D\%%F" "%%~nD-Newspaper A- %%F"
    )
    )

Answer (score 0):

Test this on some sample folders/files:

```
@echo off
set "folder=C:\Test\Newspaper A"
for %%a in ("%folder%") do set "root=%%~nxa"
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir "%folder%\*.pdf" /s /b /a-d ^| findstr /vi /c:" - %root% - "') do (
   for %%b in ("%%~pa\.") do ren "%%a" "%%~nxb - %root% - %%~nxa"
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your efforts in such a quick time foxidrive, but MC ND has resolved it in his comment above. I gave your code a try, and it didn't seem to be correctly identifying the files during the directory recursion.

Comment: You're right.  The `%%F` had to be changed to `%%a` as I have edited above.